# How to call controller method from jsp using ajax

Tags: ajax, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using spring boot, maven 3.2.5.
I am working on simple maven webapp using spring boot following mvc  pattern.
i am trying to call controller method from jsp suing ajax.

this is my jsp javascript method look like , which call the ajax call to call the controller method.

```js
function listExistingUser()
 { 
 
 alert("listExistingUser");

  $.ajax({
   type : "GET",
   url : '${home}/loginController/listExistingUser',
   dataType : "json",
      crossDomain:true,
   success : function(data) {
    //console.log(data);
    //alert(data.toString());
    checkValidUser(data); 
   },
   error : function(data) {
     
   }
   });
 }
```

Bellow is my controller class.

```html
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/loginController")
public class LoginController {
 
 @Autowired
 LoginService loginService;
 
 @RequestMapping(value = "/listExistingUser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  @ResponseBody
 public Object getAuthentication(@ModelAttribute("studentId") int studentId,
      HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      {
    System.out.println("listExistingUser is called in controller");
      }
}
```

when I run my application, I am able to access login.jsp from the bellow url
`http://localhost:9090/seperation-management/pages/login.jsp`

when i hit submit button my jsp page javascript method is also getting called that is `alert("listExistingUser");`
but i am not able to called my controller method.

where I am making mistake. can anyone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's some changes to be made in the contoller method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/listExistingUser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Object> getAuthentication(){
System.out.println("listExistingUser is called in controller");
return new ResponseEntity<Object>(object,HttpStatus.OK); 
}
```

you dont need to have `@modelAttribute` annotation since you are not binding any object with the request. and it is a good practise to return `ResponseEntity` instead of returning an `Object`.

if you need to get an id from an  incoming request 
like this `siteName/listExistingUser/1`  then use this method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/listExistingUser/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Object> getAuthentication(@PathVariable("id") int id){}
```

if you want to get values from a url like this 
`siteName/listExistingUser?id=1` then use this method instead.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/listExistingUser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Object> getAuthentication(@RequestParam("id") int id){}
```

Answer (score 0):

This example is working in my Application:

**JSP:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        function getDesc() {
            $.getJSON("desclist.json", {
                sel1Id : $('select#COMPSNT_NM').val()
            }, function(data) {
                var html = '';
                var len = data.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    html += '<option value="' + data[i] + '">'
                            + data[i] + '</option>';
                }
                $('select#COMPSNT_DS').html(html);
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#COMPSNT_NM').change(function() {
                getDesc();
            });
        });
</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "desclist.json")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public @ResponseBody List<String> sectionList(@RequestParam(value = "sel1Id", required = true) String sel1Id,
        ModelMap modelMap) {

    List<PARAM_SEQ_2> list = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    list = paramSeq2Service.findByField2(sel1Id);
    for (PARAM_SEQ_2 prm : list) {
        list2.add(prm.getCOMPSNT_DS());
    }
    return list2;

}
```